# How to solve ADMM for TV Minimization Problem For Different Sizes $A$ and $x$ in $Ax=b$

Tags: image-processing, matlab, convex-optimization, total-variation

I have matrix $A$ that is $(M \times M)$ square matrix, $x$ $(M \times N)$ matrix, $b$ is $(M \times N)$ matrix. Knowing $A$ and $b$ I would like to get the $x$ from the equation $Ax=b$. $N=p \times q$, so consider $x$ as an $M$ number of $p \times q$ pixel images. These images are sparse when we take total variational $TV(x)$. I would like to solve the following minimization problem for $x$;

Define an operator $g(x)=\parallel x^T\parallel_2,$ or $g(x)=\parallel x^T\parallel_1,$ that maps $M \times N  \mapsto  N \times 1$.

$$\min  \frac{1}{2}\parallel Ax-b\parallel^2_2+k\parallel z\parallel_1,$$ subject to $Fg(x)-z=0$.

$F$ is the difference matrix to take numerical gradient of pixels.

Unlike in the deblurring+denoising problem, my matrix $A$ and $x$ are in different sizes.

The ADMM (Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers) solution to my minimization problem is given as:

$$x^{k+1}=(A^TA+pF^TF)^{-1}(A^Tb+pF^T(z^k-u^k))$$

$$z^{k+1}=S_{t/p}(Fx^{k+1}+u^{k})$$

$$u^{k+1}=u^k+Fx^{k+1}-z^{k+1}$$

When calculating $x^{k+1}$ the matrix dimensions are not compatible in my case. Gradient matris should be applied to total number of pixels $N$, $F$ matrix should have $N$ columns. So the term $(A^TA+pF^TF)$ is not proper way to add 2 matrices.

**How can I overcome this and find a solution to my problem?**

Comment: Which matrix multiplication exactly causes the dimension mismatch? At first glance they do look okay. $p$ is a scalar, right?

Comment: Yes $p$ is scalar. The dimension mismatch is addition of $A^TA$ and $F^TF$. $F$ is a scalar gradient operator which should be applied to all pixels of $x$. Since total number of pixels in $x$ is $N$, $F$ should be $NxN$.

Comment: @Florian what do you think about my question?

Comment: I don't understand the source of mismatch. $A$ multiplies $x$ in your cost function and $F$ multiplies $x$ in your constraint. Hence $A$ and $F$ have the same number of columns. Hence $A^T A$ and $F^T F$ are exactly the same size.

Comment: A is not applied to pixels in x. Thats why it is $M \times M$ @Florian

Comment: Huh, weird, your problem formulation looks like $x$ should be a vector, not a matrix. Anyways: If $A$ is $M \times M$ then $F$ needs to have $M$ columns as well. Otherwise your constraint $Fx - z = 0$ makes no sense.

Comment: I edited my question. Now we apply another operator to x before F. Can you check my question again? @Florian

Comment: I don't understand your operator $g(x)$. How does it map $M \times N$ to $N \times 1$? Do you mean $(M\cdot N) \times 1$ maybe (i.e., a vectorization)?

Comment: $g(x)= \parallel x^T\parallel_2$, norm is taken for every row. @Florian

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105196/discussion-between-johanson-and-florian).

Answer (score 0):

#### The Error in the Model

The problem is in the dimensions of the Linear Operator $ A $ in your model compared to the Data Matrix $ X $. The number of columns of the matrix $ A $ must match the number of pixels in each column of $ X $ (Each image). While in your case it matches the number of images.

#### Matrix Form of 2D Linear Operator

Let's try to build the model correctly. Assume our data (Images) is given by the set of 2D matrices $ {\left\{ {X}_{i} \right\}}_{i = 1}^{m} $ where $ {X}_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times q} $. Given a Linear Operator $ \mathcal{A}: \mathbb{R}^{p \times q} \to \mathbb{R}^{k \times l} $ and we have $ {B}_{i} = \mathcal{A} \left( {X}_{i} \right) $.

In order to create the matrix form we should represent the Linear Operator by the matrix $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{\left( k l \right) \times \left( p q \right)} $ which is the matrix which applies the operator on the Column Stacked (See [Vectorization Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))) vectors. So we have $ \boldsymbol{x}_{i} = \operatorname{Vec} \left( {X}_{i} \right) $ and $ \boldsymbol{b}_{i} = \operatorname{Vec} \left( {B}_{i} \right) $.

By defining $ X = \left[ \boldsymbol{x}_{1}, \boldsymbol{x}_{2}, \ldots \boldsymbol{x}_{m} \right] $ and $ B = \left[ \boldsymbol{b}_{1}, \boldsymbol{b}_{2}, \ldots \boldsymbol{b}_{m} \right] $ we have $ A X = B $.

With this definition everything will work as expected. Same logic will work for $ F $.

**Remark**

If you want $ F $ to work along the rows of $ X $ then set $ Z = F {X}^{T} $.

#### ADMM for the Vector Case

First, pay attention that the ADMM works on vectors (You can work with Matrices but then you need to update the Prox operations accordingly.

So $ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \boldsymbol{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{m} $ and $ F \in \mathbb{R}^{o \times n} $ where $ o $ is set to match the operation of TV on the image columns and rows which $ \boldsymbol{x} $ is a column stack of.

So now the terms do align propely: $ {\left( {A}^{T} A + p {F}^{T} F \right)}^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ and $ \left( {A}^{T} \boldsymbol{b} + p {F}^{T} \left( \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{u} \right) \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $. So the calculation of $ \boldsymbol{x}^{k} $ is well defined.

Given that $ \boldsymbol{z} \in \mathbb{R}^{o} $ and $ \boldsymbol{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{o} $ their calculation is also well defined.

I guess something in your code doesn't match. But if the code have the terms $ A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{b} $ and $ F \boldsymbol{x} $ well defined then everything else will work.

Comment: Yes with dimensions you gave it should work. But I have different dimensions. So how can I solve the problem with matrices that i stated in my question?

Comment: It works with your dimensions the same way. Again, once you have $ A X - B $ working and $ F X $ well defined all the rest will work.

Comment: Total number of pixels in $x$ is $N$ and I need to apply F to take gradient of pixels values in $x$. So $F$ should be $NxN$ Matrix which cannot add to $A^TA$ because it is $MxM$

Comment: This is what you miss. The right way to do this is column stack the image. If the image is $ p \times q $ then your vector $ \boldsymbol{x} $ has the length $ n = p \times q $. From there follow what's in my answer.

Comment: If the image is $p \times q$ my $x$ is $M \times p \times q$. Then taking $N=p \times q$ I can write $x$ as $M x N$. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your data set. You have $ M $ images with the same size. What exactly are you after? Applying for each the Total Variation Deblurring? So in order to be efficient you stack all images (Each as a column vector) into a matrix?

Comment: Please do not consider my problem as image debulurring+denoising problem because it is not. I know $A$, $b$, the relationship $Ax=b$. I also know gradient of $x$ is sparse. Thast why I would like to approach the problem as TV minimaztion. When I get the $M \times p \times q$ 3D matrix $x$ I will sum the $M$ 'images' and get the final image. I am not sure if I can say I have $M$ images.

Comment: Again, we need to understand the data structure of your problem. Do you have Matrices where you want to operate on each column or what?

Comment: I cant see what is unclear in my problem. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: I want to write MATLAB Code for the problem. Should I generate $ M $ 2D Matrices of $ p \times q $? Now, the matrix $ A $ should be working on each image in a column stack form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105121/discussion-between-royi-and-johanson).

Comment: @johanson, Anything missing in my answer? Could you please mark it?