# Solve Efficiently the 1D Total Variation Regularized Least Squares Problem (Denoising / Deblurring)

Tags: denoising, deconvolution, optimization, inverse-problem, total-variation

How to solve a 1D Least Squares with Total Variation Regularization?
I know gradient based methods, I wonder how much faster / efficient I can get.

Comment: Could you please split it to $ {L}_{1} $ and Total Variation? Namely a question for each?

Answer (score 3):

I will answer Total Variation Regularization:

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} f \left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| D \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1} $$

Now, we can use the method of [Majorization Minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MM_algorithm) to solve this:

$$ \forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \; \frac{ {t}^{2} }{ 2 \left| {t}_{k} \right| } + \frac{\left| {t}_{k} \right|}{2} \geq \left| t \right| \Leftrightarrow \forall \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \; \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{x}^{T} {D}^{T} \Lambda_{k}^{-1} D \boldsymbol{x} + \frac{1}{2} {\left\| D \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right\|}_{1} \geq {\left\| D \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1} $$

Where:

$$ \Lambda_{k} = \operatorname{Diag} \left( \left| D \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right| \right) $$

Hence our iteration can be built using:

$$ \boldsymbol{x}_{k + 1} = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} g \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right) $$

Where $ g \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right) = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} \boldsymbol{x}^{T} {D}^{T} \Lambda_{k}^{-1} D \boldsymbol{x} + \frac{\lambda}{2} {\left\| D \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right\|}_{1} $

One could check that indeed:

1. $ g \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right) = f \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right) $.
2. $ g \left( \boldsymbol{y} \right) \geq f \left( \boldsymbol{y} \right) $.

Hence:

$$\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{x}_{k + 1} & = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} g \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right) && \text{} \\
& = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} \boldsymbol{x}^{T} {D}^{T} \Lambda_{k}^{-1} D \boldsymbol{x} + \frac{\lambda}{2} {\left\| D \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right\|}_{1}  && \text{} \\
& = {\left( {A}^{T} A + \lambda {D}^{T} \Lambda_{k}^{-1} D \right)}^{-1} {A}^{T} \boldsymbol{y} && \text{} \\
& = {\left( {A}^{T} A \right)}^{-1} - {\left( {A}^{T} A \right)}^{-1} {D}^{T} \left( \frac{1}{\lambda} \Lambda_{k} + D {\left( {A}^{T} A \right)}^{-1} {D}^{T} \right) D {\left( {A}^{T} A \right)}^{-1} {A}^{T} \boldsymbol{y} && \text{}
\end{aligned}$$

Where the last step is from the [Matrix Inversion Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) ([Woodbury Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)) and prevents the case where some elements of the diagonal matrix are close to zero.

This is actually another derivation of the [Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) method.

This method will be very effective for small to medium sized problems.
For large problems it is better to reformulate it as a Regularized Least Squares:

$$\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{x}_{k + 1} & = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} g \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right) && \text{} \\
& = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} {\left\| {\Lambda}_{k}^{-\frac{1}{2}} D \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{2}^{2}
\end{aligned}$$

An use a specific solver (Assuming $ A $ is sparse).

Comparing it to another efficient solver (See [How to Solve Image Denoising with Total Variation Prior Using ADMM](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75231)) for the case $ A = I $ (Denoising):

[image]

[image]

While the run time is very similar and comparable (ADMM is ~20% faster per iteration) one could see that the MM based method converges faster. It is no surprise as it is basically a [Fixed Point method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration).

The code is available at my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q76446 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q76446` folder).

Comment: This is great. I will open a dedicated question for the case $D=I$. Is there a special optimization for that case?